# Defining a class in python in python

Tags: python, class, self

```
class Rectangle(object):

def __init__(self, (top left corner), width, height):
    """
    __init__(self, (x, y), integer, integer)
    """

    self._x = x
    self._y = y
    self._width = width
    self._height = height

def get_bottom_right(self):
    x + self.width = d
    y + self.height = t

return '' + d,t
```

so i am trying to make a class for a rectangle, i am trying to find the bottom right of the rectangle. the bottom right of the rectangle can be found by adding the height and width onto the top left corner. eg. (2,3),4,7 would make the bottom corner be (6,10). however, i dont believe my code is right. this is my first time using classes so some hints and tricks on how to interpret this would be very helpful.

Comment: When you post code, you could make sure it's formatted correctly, since it matters in python.

Comment: sorry, i'll keep that in mind next time i post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is this

```
class Rectangle(object):
  def __init__(self, top_corner, width, height):
    self._x = top_corner[0]
    self._y = top_corner[1]
    self._width = width
    self._height = height

  def get_bottom_right(self):
    d = self._x + self.width
    t = self._y + self.height
    return (d,t)
```

You can use this like this

```
# Makes a rectangle at (2, 4) with width
# 6 and height 10
rect = new Rectangle((2, 4), 6, 10) 

# Returns (8, 14)
bottom_right = rect.get_bottom_right
```

Also, you could probably save yourself some time by making a `Point` class

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Comment: thank you, this is what i wanted. i didn't know how to define top_corner with x and y.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Rectangle(object):
  def __init__(self, pos, width, height):
    self._x = pos[0]
    self._y = pos[1]
    self._width = width
    self._height = height
  def get_bottom_right(self):
    d = self._x + self._width
    t = self._y + self._height
    return d,t
```

The code is running here: http://codepad.org/VfqMfXrt

Comment: i want to find the bottom of the rectangle. basically i want to add the topleftcorner(which will be x,y) and add the width to x and the height to y. thanks for your reply though